# How can I combine multiple webpages and get them as pdf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have multiple pages that I am getting after filling a form with puppeteer. I am currently using "page.printToPDF" api of puppeteer to obtain the webpage as a pdf but the problem is that I have multiple pages and I would like to combine all of them and get a single pdf. Is there anyway I can achieve this with puppeteer and javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution, there are many packages for merging pdf files.

[image]

Here is how you can use one of the many pdf merging packages.

```
const PDFMerge = require('pdf-merge');
const files = [
    `${__dirname}/1.pdf`,
    `${__dirname}/2.pdf`
];
const finalFile = `${__dirname}/final.pdf`;
```

Here is how you can print multiple pages and then merge them.

```
// goto first page and save pdf file
await page.goto('http://example1.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
await page.pdf({path: files[0], format: 'A4', printBackground: true})

// goto first page and save pdf file
await page.goto('http://example2.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
await page.pdf({path: files[1], format: 'A4', printBackground: true})

// merge two of them and save to another file
await PDFMerge(files, {output: finalFile);
```

It's all about how you take advantages of your resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('https://www.google.co.in/', 'utf8');
var options = { 
  format: 'A4',
  "border": {
    "top": "0.2in",            // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
    "bottom": "1in",
    "left": "0.1cm",
    "right": "0.1cm"
  },
};

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./google.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

You have to install `html-pdf` after this use above code. for more information about to convert check link. https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Comment: Can I use this to combine multiple HTML? From what I see this can be used to convert only a single HTML to pdf.